# WPF MVVM: Exception 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' thrown when opening WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, .net-3.5

I have below helper to show or close a given window:

```
public static class Splasher
{
    private static Window mSplash;

    public static Window SplashScreen
    {
        get
        {
            return mSplash;
        }
        set
        {
            mSplash = value;
        }
    }

    public static void ShowSplashScreen()
    {
        if (mSplash != null)
        {
            try
            {
                mSplash.Show();  // <--- HERE IT THROWS EXCEPTION
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void ShowDialogSplashScreen()
    {
        if (mSplash != null)
        {
            mSplash.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    public static void CloseSplashScreen()
    {
        if (mSplash != null)
        {
            mSplash.Close();

            if (mSplash is IDisposable)
            {
                (mSplash as IDisposable).Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also I have below WPF Window:

```
<Window x:Class="My.Tools.XAML.Controls.Windows.WpfSplashScreen"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:My.Tools.XAML.Controls.Windows"

    xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"    

    ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None"  
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"        
    Title="WpfSplashScreen" 
    Height="305" Width="585" 
    Loaded="Window_Loaded">

    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/My.Tools.XAML;component/Resources/Background.jpg"/>
    </Window.Background>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="8 5 0 0">
                <Image x:Name="Logo" Width="24" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Label x:Name="ScreenTitle" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" FontSize="11.25" Foreground="White" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">ScreenTitle</Label>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
                <Label x:Name="MinimizeButton" FontFamily="Webdings" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" MouseLeftButtonUp="MinimizeButton_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseEnter="MinimizeButton_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="MinimizeButton_MouseLeave">0</Label>
                <Label x:Name="CloseButton" FontFamily="Webdings" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" MouseLeftButtonUp="CloseButton_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseEnter="CloseButton_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="CloseButton_MouseLeave">r</Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label x:Name="Message" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
                   FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" FontSize="36" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold" 
                   Foreground="White" Content="Message"/>            

            <Label x:Name="Submessage" 
                   Margin="0 0 0 25"
                   FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" FontSize="10" Foreground="White"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                   Content="Submessage"/>

            <Image x:Name="img" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label x:Name="CurrentTask"
                   Margin="8 0 0 3"
                   FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" FontSize="18" FontStyle="Italic"  
                   Foreground="White" 
                   Content="Loading"
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"/>

            <Label x:Name="Dots" 
                   Margin="0 0 0 3"
                   FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" FontSize="18" FontStyle="Italic"  
                   Foreground="White"
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom">
            <Label.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Label.Loaded">
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content" Duration="00:00:00.8" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value=""/>
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="."/>
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4" Value=".."/>
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.6" Value="..."/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Label.Style>
        </Label>
            </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window code-behind:

```
public partial class WpfSplashScreen : Window
{
    public WpfSplashScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public WpfSplashScreen(string waitMessage, string message, string submessage, string screenTitle, Icon icon)
        : this()
    {
        ImageSource imageSource = icon.ToImageSourceW();
        this.Icon = imageSource;
        this.logo = imageSource;

        this.CurrentTask.Content = waitMessage;
        this.Message.Content = message;
        this.Submessage.Content = submessage;
        this.ScreenTitle.Content = screenTitle;
        this.Logo.Source = logo;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.UriSource = new Uri("/My.Tools.XAML;component/Resources/metroProgressBar.gif", UriKind.Relative);
        image.EndInit();
        ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(img, image);

        ImageBehavior.SetAutoStart(img, true);
        ImageBehavior.SetRepeatBehavior(img, RepeatBehavior.Forever);
    }

    // Other stuff
}
```

When my program starts I perform below to open the splash screen from a background thread created in view model:

```
Splasher.SplashScreen = new WpfSplashScreen("Loading",
                        entryAssemblyInfo.ProductTitle,
                        string.Format("Version {0}",
                        entryAssemblyInfo.Version),
                        entryAssemblyInfo.ProductTitle,
                        GetWindowIcon());

Splasher.SplashScreen.Closed += OnSplashScreenClosed;
Splasher.ShowSplashScreen();
```

When I call Splasher.ShowSplashScreen(), then the method within Splasher helper class is invoked:

```
    public static void ShowSplashScreen()
    {
        if (mSplash != null)
        {
            try
            {
                mSplash.Show();  // <--- HERE IT THROWS EXCEPTION
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message); // despite exception is thrown it never reaches here.
            }
        }
    }
```

Within above method, when debugging and after pressing F11, line mSplash.Show() is throwing below exception:

> an unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll

Anyway the program executes correctly. Window is opened correctly. This exception is shown in output window when debugging.

This occurs previous to Window_Loaded method, so I suppose it is something when loading xaml view. According to microsoft this exception means the program did not find some file I specified. The only file I have specified in WpfSplashScreen WPF Window is the background in the view:

```
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/My.Tools.XAML;component/Resources/Background.jpg"/>
</Window.Background>
```

Background.jpg properties is set as a Resource in compilation action, and do not copy.

and within Window_Loaded event the animated progressbar gif but Window_Loaded has not been executed yet (the exception is thrown before this).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure all the images that used by XAML file  exist (like Background.jpg etc)

Comment: @Evyatar Yes, they exists.I have updated post: the program executes correctly. Window is opened correctly. This exception is shown in output window when debugging.

Comment: Set your debugger to break on this type of exception, then look at the callstack and/or inner exception to see if there is any more information about what is throwing

Comment: File not found - should be very easy to solve, you just need to see which file is not being found and from which path the system is trying to load it from. to do that you will have to do as LordWilmore suggested - and when the system break on the exception you will be able to drill in the exception to find out this information.

Comment: @LordWilmore Oh my God! I have found the exact point where this exception is caused by doing what LordWilmore has suggested. A lot of thanks!!! It was caused by a webservice that is trying to call. Better to post in another post I think.